# SignalR breaks on every other page refresh until I do a ctrl+F5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

SignalR is working great except on every other page load, I get:

[image: errors]

The error in the start and abort are

**Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection.**

At this point, though, if I do a ctrl+f5, it works great.

I'm on IIS 7.5 which means it's not using web sockets, if that matters.

Comment: Is your session expiring? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/introduction-to-security#reconcile

Comment: I've run into the same issue, have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that another request that completes after SignalR's /negotiate request but before the /start request is setting a cookie that is changing the user's `IPrincipal`?

SignalR's /negotiate request returns a "connectionToken" (among other things) which serves as an anti-CSRF token. Every subsequent SignalR request includes the connectionToken in the query string, and the server verifies that the same user that requested the connectionToken is making the new request. If the user not the same , SignalR will respond with a 403.

As Marcel N. pointed out, this could also be caused by a user's session expiring, because that would effectively cause the user to log out. I think it's pretty unlikely that the session would consistently expire between the /negotiate and /start request however.